# Firebase Realtime Database Data Automatically Gets Deleted after some time

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase real-time database for storing data of chats.

Data is automatically getting deleted after some time from the database. I tried changing rules and everything but it keeps on getting deleted after some time. No body apart from me has access to the DB. I tried creating a new firebase project but same thing happens.

My rule for the Firebase realtime database looks as below:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

**Post message code:**

```
const postMessage = async (receiverUserId, message, user) => {
  const { senderUserId, senderType, receiverType,receiverDetails,senderDetails } =
    await getSenderReceiverDetails(user, receiverUserId);
  const senderMessage = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(
      "chatRoom/messages/" +
        senderType +
        "_" +
        senderUserId +
        "/" +
        receiverType +
        "_" +
        receiverUserId
    );
  const receiverMessage = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(
      "chatRoom/messages/" +
        receiverType +
        "_" +
        receiverUserId +
        "/" +
        senderType +
        "_" +
        senderUserId
    );

  senderMessage.push({
    message: message,
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    source: "SENDER",
  });
  receiverMessage.push({
    message: message,
    timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    source: "RECEIVER",
  });
  const tokenDoc = await UserToken.findOne({
    where: {
      user_id: receiverUserId,
      status: "active",
      user_type: receiverType,
    },
  });
  if (tokenDoc) {
    const fcmToken = tokenDoc.dataValues.fcm_token;
    if (fcmToken && fcmToken != "") {
      notificationService.sendNotification("New message",senderDetails.name + ": " + message, fcmToken);
    }
  }
};
```

**Get messages:**

```
const getMessages = async (user, receiverUserId) => {
  const {
    senderUserId,
    senderType,
    receiverType,
    senderDetails,
    receiverDetails,
  } = await getSenderReceiverDetails(user, receiverUserId);
  // console.log("senderUserId: ", senderUserId, " senderType ====> ", senderType, receiverType);
  const chatRoomRef = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(
      "chatRoom/messages/" +
        senderType +
        "_" +
        senderUserId +
        "/" +
        receiverType +
        "_" +
        receiverUserId
    );
  const bookingRef = firebase
    .database()
    .ref(
      "chatRoom/booking/" +
        senderType +
        "_" +
        senderUserId +
        "/" +
        receiverType +
        "_" +
        receiverUserId
    );

  // Use Promise.all to wait for both data requests to complete
  const [chatRoomSnapshot, bookingSnapshot] = await Promise.all([
    chatRoomRef.once("value"),
    bookingRef.once("value"),
  ]);

  let messageObj = [];
  const chatRoomData = chatRoomSnapshot.val();
  if (chatRoomData !== null) {
    messageObj = Object.values(chatRoomData);
  }

  let bookingObj = null;
  const bookingData = bookingSnapshot.val();
  console.log("booinggggggg====>",bookingData);
  if (bookingData !== null) {
    const bookingValues = Object.values(bookingData);
    console.log("hiiiiiiiii===>",bookingValues);
    if (bookingValues.length > 0) {
      bookingObj = bookingValues[bookingValues.length - 1];
    }
  }

  // get the sender's name and profile URL from the `user` object
  const senderName = senderDetails.name;
  const senderProfileUrl = senderDetails.profile_pic;

  const receiverName = receiverDetails.name;
  const receiverProfileUrl = receiverDetails.profile_pic;
  const profileDetails = {
    senderName,
    senderProfileUrl,
    receiverName,
    receiverProfileUrl,
  };

  // console.log("messageObj =========> ", messageObj);
  console.log("bookingObj ========> ", bookingObj);
  return { messageObj, bookingObj, profileDetails };
};
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database does not have any built-in functionality to delete data after some time, so if the data is getting deleted after some time you must have some application code that does that. I don't immediately see what part of the code you shared could be causing this though, as `push()` will always generate a new unique child path - it should never delete existing data. So I recommend checking the rest of your code for writes to the database. If you can't find it that way, consider setting up a minimal repro on a site like jsbin, stackblitz, or similar.